# Grammar for all words $0^n1^m$ such that $n \ge m+2$

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

Given grammar
$$L(G) = \{ 0^n1^m | n \ge m + 2 \}$$
What is the grammar for this?
I know the grammar for the following language:
$$ L(A) = \{ 0^n1^m | n = m + 2 \} $$
We can divide any string in $L(A)$ in the following substrings:

- prefix $00$
- the suffix $0^n1^n$
  hence one of the grammars is :
  $$S \rightarrow 00A \\ A \rightarrow 0A1 | \epsilon$$
  The above grammar in question is similar so I can divide any string as
- prefix $00$
- substring $0^*$
- suffix $0^n1^n$
  Am I heading in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is the right direction.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: @D.W. Oh, apologies for that. I will keep this in mind next time while asking a new question.